# Stable sampling of large Gaussian distributions

Tags: numpy, eigen, gaussian

I'm trying to sample a Gaussian distribution of covariance matrix `P` that is `N` by `N`, with `N` very large (around 4000 ).

Usually one would proceed like so:

1. Compute the Cholesky decomposition of `P` : `L`, such that `L * L.T = P`
2. Sample a normal Gaussian distribution : `X ~N(0,I_N)`, where `I_N` is the identity and `N = 4000`
3. Obtain the desired sample `Y` from `Y = L * X`

The snag here is in the computation of `L`. The algorithm does not seem to be stable for such a large matrix, as the computed Cholesky decomposition does not satisfy `L * L.T != P`.

I've tried to normalize `P` before computing its Cholesky decomposition (dividing it by its largest value), to no avail. I'm using the C++ library Eigen, and I've noticed this problem with numpy as well.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cholesky decomposition should be quite stable, if the input matrix is actually positive definite. It can have issues if the matrix is (near) semi- or in-definite.
In that case you can use the LDLT decomposition instead. For an input `A` it computes a permutation `P`, a unit-diagonal triangular `L` and a diagonal `D`, such that

```
 A = P.T*L*D*L.T*P
```

Then instead of multiplying `Y = L * X` you need of course `Y = sqrt(D) * L * X`, where `sqrt(D)` is an element-wise sqrt (I don't know the python syntax for that).

Note that you can ignore the permutation, since permuting a vector of identically independent distributed random numbers, is still a vector of i.i.d. numbers.

If that still does not work, try using the `SelfAdjointEigenSolver`-decomposition.
This computes a diagonal matrix of Eigenvalues `D` and a unitarian matrix `V` of Eigenvectors, such that

```
A = V * D * V^{-1}
```

And you can do essentially the same as above. (Note that for unitarian matrices, `V^{-1}` is just the adjoint of `V`, i.e., `V^{-1} = V^T` in the real-valued case).

Comment: Thanks, I've ended up doing a self-adjoint matrix decomposition and it did the trick

Comment: Also, very minor comment but your last equation should read 
`A = V * D * V^T` , as it would be a shame to not use the orthogonality of V to your benefit = )

Comment: @FrenchOwl I added a note for that.